# Stored procedure on OVHCloud MySQL server fails with Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-8.0, ovhcloud

I'm using the jaro winkler stored procedure here: https://gist.github.com/TheHiddenHaku/7229861. This runs fine on my local MySQL server (version 8.0.19) but when trying to use the same function on OVHCloud MySQL server (version 8.0.26) it's failing with the error `Unknown column '' in 'field list'`.

I'm testing with various statements:

```
select jws('test','test1')
select jws("test","test1")
select jws(myColumn, 'test1') from myTable;
```

And all queries result in the same error.

Comment: What code line causes this error?

Comment: PS. I cannot find something which may result in shown error. Check does the function text is entered correctly.

Comment: I've since solved this with the help of some folk on the OVH Discord. They're going to post an answer so as to create a little knowledge base on the subject. Thanks for looking :)

Comment: Please post self-answer and describe the solution, at least briefly. If you can predict where this "little knowledge base" will be published then give the link. This may help somebody else.

Comment: I was waiting for someone else to post - it's all good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your server is using `sql_mode=''`.
OVHCloud MySQL server has sql_mode `ANSI,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,STRICT_ALL_TABLES`.

ANSI activates the ANSI_QUOTES mode which interprets double quotes (`"`) as fields name.
Your jaro winkler stored procedure uses double quotes to define strings string="value" (l.16, 17 and 38).

Without `ANSI_QUOTES`, MySQL reads: variable string is equal to value.

With `ANSI_QUOTES`, MySQL reads: variable string is equal to value of field called "value".

You need to update your stored procedure to use single quotes (`'`) for string definition.

```
...
set common1='';
set common2='';
...
set in2 = concat(substr(in2,1,curSub-1),concat('0',substr(in2,curSub+1,length(in2)-curSub+1)));
```

Comment: @Akina I posted the comment in the link once we found the solution to this issue so that no one else has the same pain :)

Comment: ;) I have not payed attention to the fact that doublequotes are used - this is an axiom for me that `"` may/must be used only in JSON processing...